# How do I achieve Break Damage Limit on standard attacks?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

In most Final Fantasy games, your characters need to meet a special condition in order to increase their damage further than the base limit. In Final Fantasy X, your weapon required *Break Damage Limit* customization; in Final Fantasy XIII, you required a *Tier 3* upgraded weapon; so on, so forth.

In Final Fantasy XV, you can achieve Break Damage Limit for Techniques and Link-Strikes via the Ascension Skill Tree for 999 AP. I looked through the different trees, but I did not an option for Break Damage Limit on standard attacks.

How do I achieve Break Damage Limit on standard attacks? Do I need a special weapon or accessory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Break Damage Limit is only available for Links and tech, and is not possible to achieve with standard attacks sadly

Comment: Well that's unfortunate. Oh well, I guess they updated it to encourage using those abilities

Comment: This isnt entirely accurate. You can also craft spells that break the damage limit with certain catalysts. That doesnt, however make regular attacks able to overcome the limit still.

Answer (score 0):

It's worth noting that it is possible to break damage limit with standard noctis attacks with blindside. I think you need to unlock link-strike break dmg limit, but my 99 noctis pretty regularly hits for 13k ish with blindsides. With a little practice it's pretty easy to get blindsides regularly and if you are using the right weapon. You can do great damage. It hits even harder with ignis' elemental buff when enemies have elemental weakness.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately you cannot achieve limit break damage with regular attacks, outside of Armiger. You can however achieve limit break for your warp strikes, as you've discovered.

I would alter your setup a bit, though. I use Ragnarok for my warp strikes. I regularly do 35K+ without using Ignus's enhancement tech, and 70-99K with the enhancement tech.

I would also recommend that you utilize a high health and attack boosting meal. I either use the Golden Soup(100% guaranteed critical hits, +150% HP regen) or Longwhythe's Peak(+600 attack stat, +4,000 health, +200% HP regen). Depending on the goal, enemies involved, etc. For the Menace dungeons I used Longwhythe's Peak. It provides a very healthy boost.

My current setup is Ragnarok as my main warp striker, Plumes of the Vortex as my main melee striker(Zwill Crossblades are a great option as well). With the Axe of the Conqueror and Sword of the Father specifically for their attack stat bonuses. With Adamantite Bangle to push my health, Rare Metal to break the limit, and Robes of the Lord to boost MP regen.

You could also use the Black Hood to help you avoid incoming attacks, rather than Robe of the Lord. Unfortunately, the heavy use of Reflex Enhancer is not an option in Costlemark Dungeon.

Answer (score -2):

Actually you can with an item but no not through ascension, I think it's Zu beak or something like that